# Как создать директорию внутри контейнера после подъема

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Необходимо в docker-compose.yml сделать следующее, чтобы после подъема контeйнера nginx, в нем создавалась папка.
(часть docker-compose.yml, собственно все как обычно)

`nginx:
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - 80:80
      volumes:
        - ./volumes/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
      networks:
        - network`

И по факту необходимо в данном же контейнере создать папку /tmp и задать права доступа к ней на чтение/запись.
Каким образом это можно сделать именно в .yml?

Comment: Нужно было еще тег docker добавить, может кто-то просто не был подписан на тег docker-compose, потому никто не отвечал.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Александр, за подсказку и исправления.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать новый образ с необходимой структурой директорий. Там где находится docker-compose.yml нужно создать директорию 'nginx' и в нее поместить Dockerfile с таким содержимым:

```
FROM nginx:1.15

RUN mkdir -p /путь/к/папке/1 \
    && mkdir -p /путь/к/папке/2

EXPOSE 80 443
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

В docker-compose.yml заменить 'image' на 'build':

```
nginx:
    build:
        ./nginx
    ports:
        - 80:80
    volumes:
        - ./volumes/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
        - network
```

Для того чтобы при запуске конфигурации docker-compose образы были заново построены нужно использовать ключ --build:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, я как раз искал возможный путь решения без создания собственного образа, но видимо этот вариант пока самый надежный.

От себя добавлю, что проверяю сегодня пришедший в голову вариант. При формировании volume, если указать в контейнере путь до папки, которой там нет, то она будет создана. Проверю есть ли у нее необходимые права доступа и если да, то это будет как раз вариантом без пересборки образа.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, то что мне было необходимо, заключалось в формировании volume для nginx контейнера. По указанным путям автоматически создаются необходимые папки с необходимыми правами.